# How to serialize a django QuerySet and a django object in one call?

Tags: python, django, serialization

I am trying to retrieve my object and a query set from my model through an ajax call.
What I want to get back is an object and a query set. So when i serialize the object its no problem but the QuerySet does not seem to be serialized by Django.
I get an error "QuerySet has no attribute _meta".

Here is my code:

```
def followUp(request):
    fid = request.GET['fid']
    fup = FollowUp.objects.get(answer=fid)
    Question = fup.question
    answers = Question.answer_set.all()

    context = {
        'question': Question,
        'answers' : answers
    }
    data = serializers.serialize('json', context)
    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False, content_type="application/json")
```

Here if i just put '**Question**' its no problem but as soon as i try to make a dict with '**answers**' combined,  it throws the error.

Is there a way to serialize both of them or what should I do if not?
Please Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be using JsonResponse with a serializer anyway, as this means you serialize to JSON twice.

What you should do here is to serialize each of those objects separately, to *Python* structures, then send that to JsonResponse.

```
context = {
  'question': serializers.serialize('python', [fup.question])[0],
  'answers' : serializers.serialize('python', answers)
}
return JsonResponse(context , safe=False)
```

Note that this is not really a good way of doing things, and if you are trying to do complex serialization you should really use Django REST Framework.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I am new to Django, so still exploring the options.
P.S.:  The solution works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
context = {
'question': serializers.serialize('json', Question),
'answers' : serializers.serialize('json', answers)
}
return JsonResponse(context, safe=False)
```